# Gnuplot: Plotting different functions in a loop

Tags: function, loops, gnuplot

I'd like to plot the Hermite polynomials in the same graph without having to type them one by one using a loop.  I've tried something like this:

```
    H0(x) = 1 
    H1(x) = 2*x 
    H2(x) = 4*x*x-2 
    H3(x) = 8*x**3-12*x 
    H4(x) = 16*x**4-48*x**2+12 
    H5(x) = 32*x**5-160*x**3+120*x

    plot for[i=0:5] H.i(x)
```

but It won't work, it'll say:  `undefined variable: H`. I've seen the variable `i` can be used as a string but I haven't been able to find if there's a way to use it as a string when calling a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a different approach, including the index `i` as an argument of the function:

```
H(i,x) = (i == 0 ? 1 : \
          i == 1 ? 2*x : \
          i == 2 ? 4*x*x-2 : \
          i == 3 ? 8*x**3-12*x : \
          i == 4 ? 16*x**4-48*x**2+12 : \
          i == 5 ? 32*x**5-160*x**3+120*x : 1/0)

plot for[i=0:5] H(i,x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An improvement can be

```
set term wxt persist

set xrange[-1:1]

H(i,x) = (i == 0 ? 1 : \
      i == 1 ? 2*x : \
      i == 2 ? 4*x*x-2 : \
      i == 3 ? 8*x**3-12*x : \
      i == 4 ? 16*x**4-48*x**2+12 : \
      i == 5 ? 32*x**5-160*x**3+120*x : 1/0)

plot for[i=0:5] H(i,x) title sprintf("H(").sprintf('%d',i).sprintf(",x)")
```

[Hermite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFXb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFXb.png)

Comment: The original question did not have `xrange` specified, so your answer also should not (unless its required to work). Maybe edit your answer.

Comment: Using string concatenation with the `.` operator defeats the purpose of using `sprintf()`. Also, I don't see how this is an "improvement".

Comment: I do not care about your comments

Comment: So you copied another answer, added little extra quality and don't care about comments?  I suggest to delete this answer.